# What exactly is the status of http2 server push in 2021?

Tags: http2

I am confused with the current status of http2 server push. When I google "http 2 server push" there are many search results, among them 2 results stand out,

1. [Chrome to remove HTTP/2 Push](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/http2-push-chromium-deprecation.html) published in 2020-12-01
2. [HTTP/2 Push is dead](https://evertpot.com/http-2-push-is-dead/) published in 2020-11-12

Both of them mentioned Chrome has remove server push, but other than these 2 articles there are still many articles published in 2021 introducing/explaining http2 server push.

So what exactly is the status of http2 server push as 2022 is coming ?

I am not asking an opinion-based question but a fact-based assessment. If Chrome does kills it I think it is pretty much a fact that it is dead.

--- update ---

I came across this article https://developer.chrome.com/blog/early-hints/ (published June 23, 2022). So it seems that the proposed **103 Early Hints** is their answer to unsuccessful http2 server push.

Comment: As far as i know it was indeed slated to be removed in Chromium; whether or not they have already followed through i have never tested; I think it's fair to treat it as dead (for web development anyway), the feature filled a very thin niche, and never saw much traction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a web site option it is pretty much dead. As well as Chrome’s stated position (which has not changed but also not been actioned… yet) there is a new consideration which will likely kill it off first: HTTP/3.

HTTP/3 is [already supported by 12% of websites](https://httparchive.org/reports/state-of-the-web#h3) and [20% of web traffic](https://telemetry.mozilla.org/new-pipeline/dist.html#!cumulative=0&end_date=2021-12-28&include_spill=0&keys=__none__!__none__!__none__&max_channel_version=nightly%252F97&measure=HTTP_RESPONSE_VERSION&min_channel_version=null&processType=*&product=Firefox&sanitize=1&sort_by_value=0&sort_keys=submissions&start_date=2021-12-06&table=0&trim=1&use_submission_date=0) despite not even officially being signed off yet (though it’s as near as can be).

[Chrome has not implemented push on HTTP/3](https://twitter.com/tunetheweb/status/1326466809227337729?s=21) (and seem highlighlyunlikely to given their stated position to drop it for HTTP/2) and because of that [neither has Cloudflare](https://twitter.com/simmervigor/status/1456222548308414464?s=21) (one of the leading CDNs working on HTTP/3 and powering 10% of the internet). I’m not sure of other’s position on this but with those two out that’s a big chunk of support.

Some sites will always languish on HTTP/1.1 (without push), those that adopted HTTP/2 quickly and completely enough to use push willl likely move to HTTP/3 (especially if behind a CDN like Cloudflare) so there really is very little that’ll be left behind on HTTP/2 to be able to use push. So what little usage there is of HTTP/2 push ([~1.25% of sites](https://almanac.httparchive.org/en/2021/http#the-death-of-http2-push)) will dwindle anyway until it’s a negligible amount (if it isn’t already!).

Push is dead for web browsing. Though more recently there has been a big push (pardon the pun!) by browsers and CDNs to support [103 Early Hints](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/103) - a much safer, less risky option that can deliver many of the same benefits as push.

Comment: So you were saying even http/3 would not use server push ?

Comment: HTTP/3 has Server Push in the spec (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-quic-http-34#section-4.4), but the client has to "opt-in" and Chrome does not so it cannot be used for Chrome.

Comment: I understand http3 uses QUIC to solve HOL but were you suggesting even with http3 , server push would not be a "popular" option ?

Comment: Push has many risks through over pushing a resource that is either not needed, or not the optimal resource to use the bandwidth for even if it is needed. It’s failed to live up to its promise with little evidence it improves performance even if it wasn’t risky. Hence it hasn’t taken off and hence Chrome think it should be removed.